# Suppose $\Sigma a_n$ converge conditionally, then is $\Sigma a_{2n} + \Sigma a_{2n+1}$ converge to the same sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My answer is in general no, because n-term (as n tends to infinity) should go to zero, but here I can choose my n-th term to be $a_2$. Is my reasoning right, if yes, then can someone rigorously write my line of reasoning. Also can someone give me an example which shows the answer is no?

In case question is not clear, what I am asking is $(a_1 + a_2 +...) = (a_1 + a_3 + ....+) + (a_2 + a_4 + a_6 + ..)$. If not, then give me an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take for example $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Then $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n=-\ln(2)$,
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2n}=+\infty$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2n+1}=-\infty$.

P.S. Note that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is conditionally convergent then
$$\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{2n}+\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N} a_{2n+1}$$
could be different from
$$\lim_{N\to +\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^{N} a_{2n+1}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n.$$

Comment: but how do you show $\Sigma a_{2n} + \Sigma a_{2n-1} \neq \Sigma a_{n}$. Infact the +infinity and -infinity might cancel each other to give convergence.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with $\Sigma a_{2n} + \Sigma a_{2n-1}$? See my P.S.!

Comment: yes it  could be different because  reaarangment doesn't preserve the limit. That why a general answer would be no. Now I want a specific example  to show $(a_1 +..+ a_n +..) \neq (a_1 + a_3 +...) + (a_2 + a_4 +..)$.

Comment: $\dots$ (dots) is a VERY ambiguous notation!! Use limit and partial sum!!

Comment: what i mean is reaarangment  into even and odd terms.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh You seem not to understand what you're asking, I think. Do you mean that you want a convergent sequence $a_n$ that both $\sum a_{2n}$ and $\sum a_{2n+1}$ converge and $\sum a_n\ne\sum a_{2n}+\sum a_{2n+1}$?

Comment: @CaveJohnson No. Simply put if $a_1 +.. +a_n$ is rearranged as $(a_1 + a_3 +..) + (a_2 + a_4 +..)$, then as general rule for rearrangment of conditional convergent series, the former and later sum are unequal. Now I want an example to demonstrate that. Hope its clear now.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh To make that happen, you will necessarily need both $\sum a_{2n}$ and $\sum a_{2n+1}$ diverge. All such sequences serve as an example, which is demonstrated in the answer by Robert Z and Rigel correctly. What makes you reject their answers is your idea of the non-rigorous concept "divergent+divergent=convergent". This idea may be intuitive, but unfortunately have no mathematical meanings.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Comment: I think my question was unclear, I am asking for example in which the answer is no.

Comment: The two series $\sum a_{2n}$ and $\sum a_{2n+1}$ are both divergent, whereas $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

Comment: so? sum of two divergent series can be convergent. For eg see the reaarangment section of any analysis book and you will realise that conditional convergence is same as difference between two divergent series (positive term + negative terms).

Comment: I know what a rearrangement is. Probably we do not agree on the notion of sum of a series.

Comment: I think I complicated the matter, to phrase it simply can you give me an example of a series such that $(a1+a2+...) \neq (a1+a3+....+)+(a2+a4+a6+...$.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh Where do you get the idea that "sum of two divergent series can be convergent"? The "value" of divergent series is not defined at all, so how can you sum them up?

Comment: @CaveJohnson Sorry by divergence i mean convergence to +- infinity

Comment: To say "I mean convergence to +- infinity" does not help. To say, as you say in a comment below, "the +infinity and -infinity might cancel each other to give convergence" also does not help. There is no consistent definition of $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ in any notion of arithmetic which allows you to form their sum in a way that satisfies the laws of arithmetic. Arithmetic requires sums to be well-defined: inputting the same two summands always outputs the same sum. This is not possible for $(+\infty) + (-\infty)$.